Uncaught syntax error in react JS and appwrite
I am creating a website using React Js and Appwrite and I keep getting an error:-
HomePage.jsx:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/appwrite.js?v=47c77f22' does not provide an export named 'createClient' (at HomePage.jsx:2:10)
import { createClient } from 'appwrite';


 const client = createClient({
    endpoint:'',
    project:'',
  });

when I am trying to run  my code all I can see is the white page and the uncaught error.

have you considered consulting the documentation?

i think this documentation provide enough example on how using appwrite. Instead createClient try using Client
import { Client, Account } from "appwrite";

const client = new Client();

const account = new Account(client);

client
    .setEndpoint('https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1') // Your API Endpoint
    .setProject('5df5acd0d48c2') // Your project ID
;

const promise = account.get();

promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // Success
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error); // Failure
});

